# How Convert Google Doc to PDF when send google doc as in html format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-docs

How to convert Google Doc to PDF in via Google Script
which changes need to do in below script:

\\

```
function docToHtml(docUrl) {
  let docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docUrl).getId();
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=${docId}&exportFormat=html`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`},
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    },
  ).getContentText();
}
```

\\

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the below snippet in order to get the PDF of a Google Doc:

```
function exportPDF() {
  var theDoc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID').getAs('application/pdf');
  DriveApp.createFile(theDoc);
}
```

#### Reference

- [DriveApp Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

Comment: when doc send through mail show this textinstead of attached pdf

%PDF-1.5 %���� 2 0 obj << /Linearized 1 /L 72554 /H [ 694 130 ] /O 6 /E 72277 /N 1 /T 72276 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /XRef /Length 58 /Filter /FlateDecode /DecodeParms << /Columns 5 /Predictor 12 >> /W [ 1 3 1 ] /Index [ 2 16 ] /Info 12 0 R /Root 4 0 R /Size 18 /Prev 72277 /ID [] >> stream x�cbd`�g`b``8 "�ր�F �� L�

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to send the PDF file as an attachment on an email? @sagar16

Comment: If that is the case, you can simply attach the new created PDF file from the Drive @sagar16

Comment: I create a google doc file which get value from google sheet, while sending this doc through mail I convert this doc to html template format,
Now I  want to send this doc in attached pdf format instead of html template format
so how can we do that ?

Comment: Save the doc as a PDF in Drive, like mentioned above and then attach the PDF from Drive @sagar16